# print multiple lines in shell - improving readability in provisioning a Vagrantfile

Tags: shell, nginx, vagrantfile, code-readability

I use printf to setup my Nginx settings, and it works fine, but it's awkward to read and alter; is there a better way to improve readability?

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

    sudo printf '%s\n' 'server {' 'root /home/vagrant/web;' 'index index.php index.html index.htm;' 'location / {' 'try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;' '}' 'location ~ \.php$ {' 'fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;' 'fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;' 'fastcgi_index index.php;' 'include fastcgi_params;' '}' '}' >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

    sudo service nginx start

SHELL
```

Comment: Assuming this is legal in a vagrantfile you could just use a single single-quoted string as the argument to `printf` and use literal newlines in the string.

Comment: `sudo printf` only raises permissions of the `printf` command, which is run only *after* the output file is opened, meaning it doesn't give you any elevated privileges for opening the output file, so the `sudo` given here has no benefit over the way your Vagrantfile would work if you left it out.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there is Bash on your guest machine, you could try and use nested bash [here documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). There is no guarantee that will work with Vagrantfile but it's worth a shot anyway.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    sudo /bin/bash << 'SCRIPT'
        rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default;

        cat << 'EOF' >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
            %s\n

            server {
                root /home/vagrant/web;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
                }

                location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                }
            }
EOF
        service nginx start
SCRIPT
SHELL
```

Note that EOF, SCRIPT and SHELL must be placed in the very beginning of the line. There must not be any tabs or whitespaces in front of these words.

Comment: The only obvious problem here is that you aren't quoting your heredoc sigils, so their parameter expansions are evaluated by the outer shell. `<<'EOF'` or `<<\EOF` would emit content literally, rather than trying to evaluate `$uri` based on shell variables in the shell evaluating the heredoc.

Comment: ...by contrast, `<<-SHELL` is Ruby syntax in the outer piece of a Vagrantfile, not shell, so there's no need to quote the sigil there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, you are right. Thank you for noticing this mistake. I have corrected my answer.